# function within function not working

Tags: jquery, function, alert

I have the following script:

```
$('li.cat-hider').click(function () {
    var activeID = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($('li#' + activeID).hasClass('hidethis')) {
        $('img.t-' + activeID).toggleClass('hidden', function () {
            alert('ok');
        });
        $(this).toggleClass('hidethis');
        $('img.t-' + activeID).slideToggle('slow');
    } else {
        $(this).toggleClass('hidethis');
        $('img.t-' + activeID).toggleClass('hidden').slideToggle('slow');
    }
});
```

The alert doesn't occur. Everything else toggles and works fine. I can't understand why the alert won't happen. Can someone please point out to me where I'm going wrong?

MTIA!

Comment: [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) doesn't have a call back function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ToggleClass has no callback.  See the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/). You shouldn't need one either because the class toggle occurs instantly.